# Discord.js music bot not working on linux (yet working on windows)

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, discord.js, opus

I decided to write a command for streaming music to a channel. The code I wrote -

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "hardbass",
    category: "music",
    run: async (client, message, args, servers) => {
        const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg");
        const opusscript = require("opusscript");

        if(!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.reply("Niesi vo voice channeli").then(x => x.delete(3000))

        await message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            connection.playArbitraryInput(`http://air2.radiorecord.ru:9003/hbass_320`);
          })
    }
}
```

-worked perfectly on windows, so I decided to move it to my raspberry pi(running raspbian, same node.js version - 13.3.0, also same npm version), where the bot is normally hosted. To my suprise, it did not work. The bot joined the channel, but didnt play any music. There were no error messages at all.

Comment: Probably a missing codec.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the answer yet, I experienced the same thing. My error was that Linux could not find an Opus module. Just had to `npm i discordjs/opus` in the folder the bot was in and it worked fine. When switching the bot back to my Windows PC, it threw the same error so that I had to reinstall discordjs/opus. I guess you can't have a version that's compatible with both OS's? I'm still trying to find a solution to that myself.

Comment: You dont copy/ship the node_modules folder between machines/OSs. You have to install/build the dependencies for your target OS. If you want to ship a "ready-to-use" bot for Linux, you have to install the dependencies on a Linux OS, bundle that, and deploy it. Same for Windows.