Discord.js 14 Music Bot won't play music on Ubuntu but works on Windows
I'm currently using this custom music bot with discord.js 14. While it runs smoothly on Windows, I encounter an issue when attempting to launch it from Ubuntu. The bot successfully locates music, but upon trying to load it, the music fails to start, and the bot promptly responds with a stopped message. No error log was generated.

Works on Windows 11 23H2
Not working on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

What I've tried:

Installing the @discordjs/opus package (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62719993/18463835).
Updated packages with npm update --save.
Installed ffmpeg using sudo apt install.
Tried 4-5 other music bot source codes found on GitHub; every bot encountered the same issue.
Updated Ubuntu and its packages.
Reinstalled Ubuntu from a new ISO.

Node Version:
v20.12.2 (same on Ubuntu and Windows)
Here's an image:

